# NullPointerException launching second activity with bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters, nullpointerexception, bundle

I have activity that use Google Maps and this is the code for click on marker.
As you can see it starts a second activity with parameter:

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    SQLiteDatabase dbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {"_id", "title", "addr"};
    Cursor result = dbRead.query("merchants", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    long id = 0;

    while(result.moveToNext()) {
        if (marker.getTitle().equals(result.getString(1)) && marker.getSnippet().equals(result.getString(2))) {
            id = result.getLong(0);
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewMerchant.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("id", (int)id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is part of the code of the second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewmerchant);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = b.getInt("id");

    ...
}
```

This is the LogCat:

```
05-18 19:05:34.785: D/AndroidRuntime(28444): Shutting down VM
05-18 19:05:34.785: W/dalvikvm(28444): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419317c0)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bpem/com.example.bpem.ViewMerchant}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at com.example.bpem.ViewMerchant.onCreate(ViewMerchant.java:28)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
05-18 19:05:34.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    ... 11 more
```

If in the second activity i comment this row

```
int id = b.getInt("id");
```

then it works with no error. So what's wrong with getId???

Comment: Change `b.putInt("id", (int)id);` to `intent.putExtra("id", (int)id);`

Comment: I checked b and is results to be null. Why?

Comment: Try my 1st comment...@smartmouse

Comment: I tried the solution of the first answer and i fix that problem. But now i get a new error, please have a look at my comment in the first answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to provide the bundle to the intent object.

add

```
intent.putExtras(b);
```

before `startActivity`:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("id", (int)id);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have a new error now: the first activity send id variable with "2561503679" as value, but in the second activity the value of id is "-1733463617". This is the LogCat: http://pastebin.com/NurxH5f5

Comment: use putLong/getLong instead of putInt/getInt, without casting at int of course

Comment: Moreover its a good practise to do sanity checks in oncreate while getting intent. So something like this. Bundle b; if((b=getIntent().getExtras())!=null){ //now safe }